# Download file from dynamic url by selenium & phantomjs

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm try to write a web crawler that download a CSV file by a dynamic url.

The url is like http://aaa/bbb.mcv/Download?path=xxxx.csv

I put this url to my chrome browser but I just start to download immediately and the page won't change.

I can't even find any request in develop screen.

I've tried to ways to get the file

1. put the url in selenium

   `driver.get(url)`
2. try to get file by requests lib

   `requests.get(url)`

Both didn't work...

Any advice?

Output of two ways:

1. I try to get the screen shot and it seems doesn't change the page. (just like in chrome)
2. I try to print out the data I get and it seems like as html file.
   Then open it in the browser it is a login page.

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: @Harry_pb Hi! I just update the output!

Comment: `r =requests.get()` should give you all this file in variable `r.content` or you may get error message in `r.content` - so print it to see what you get.

Comment: do you have to login in browser to get this file ? if yes then program also has to login.

Comment: @furas I just print it out and it seems like a html file.

Comment: @furas I think you got the key point!!!  I need to login to get the file and I just login in the phantomjs but now I'm downloading by requests. It's out of phantomjs right?

Comment: with requests ypu have to use `requests.Session()` to keep all cookies (they will inform server that you have  permission to get file), and you have to manually send request with login/password similar as browser.

Comment: @furas thanks! I think i just find the direction to figure out the solution! Can I just store the cookies by phantomjs and use it to request the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help!
I finally find the problem is that...
I login the website by selenium and I use requests to download the file.
**Selenium doesn't have any authentication information!**

So my solution is get the cookies by selenium first.
Then send it into the requests!

Here is my Code

```
cookies = driver.get_cookies() #selenium web driver

s = requests.Session()
for cookie in cookies:
    s.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])
response = s.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
import requests

url = '...'
save_location = '...'

session = requests.session()

response = session.get(url)
with open(save_location, 'wb') as t:
    for chunk in response.iter_content(1024):
        t.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I just get a HTML file seems like a login page.

Comment: try `requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))` with user and pass as username and password. This assumes you have access to the webpage.

Comment: I just figured out the problem! I need to send cookies with my request!